# External HD slow in Finder on Monterey

Tags: finder, hard-drive, external-disk

I have a 2020 MacBook Pro 13-inch with Monterey 12.2.1.

An old external HD of mine, a Seagate one from 2009 worked well enough on Catalina and then when I upgraded it to Big Sur; but now, in Finder, it beachballs - but ***only*** with the external HD in Finder, not any other apps.

I can open video files from it via VLC well enough.

I deleted Finder prefs, reset Finder as Group By > Name, and set the font size to a reasonable one.

As it is, Monterey works well; but the Seagate external drive is slow to load in Finder.

Is there a solution to this which would fix the beachballing? Not found beachballing when using Finder and not sure what's the best fix for this.

Comment: Regardless, I'd be looking to get my data off a 13-year-old hard drive asap, if you want to keep it.